# Preventing the user from entering < or > into form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to prevent users from entering < or > into my form fields using JavaScript.  Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    regex = new RegExp("\<|>");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

It's still allowing those characters, how do I stop this?

Comment: you used e for the event handler so use e.preventDefault() not event.preventDefault();

Comment: You won't get the last typed character in a keydown event. Try keyup. And why return false after preventDefault()?

Comment: Just a reminder to also validate this on the server side. Just because you restrict it with JS doesn't mean this can't be bypassed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why bother translating then regexing? I like to keep it simple:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
    if ((e.which == 62) || (e.which == 60)) { // greater than or less than key pressed
        e.preventDefault();
    }    
});
```

Edit to add:

Alternate if condition based on @Samsquanch feedback:

```
if ((String.fromCharCode(e.which) == '>') || (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == '<')) { // greater than or less than key pressed
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will not work cross-browser and/or cross-OS. It doesn't work for me, for example, because the `<` returns 188 and the `>` key returns 190.

Comment: @Samsquanch added alternate condition; would this be more universal?

Comment: @DigitalChris [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) indicate "yes".

Comment: Your updated solution also fails for me. For `<`, `fromCharCode` returns `¼`, and with `>`, `fromCharCode` returns `¾`.

Comment: @Samsquanch Which browser are you in? IIRC, key press support on the `Event` object has differences across browsers.

Comment: Latest builds of Chrome and FF on OSX.

Answer (score 3):

Two things worth noting:

- keypress isn't fully supported for all keys across all browsers. You should use keydown or keyup
- the `<` and `>` key code vary across OS' and keyboard layouts. Hard coding the keycodes won't consistently work

For a cross-OS and cross-keyboard-layout solution (although not as clean), you can do this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input, textarea', function (e) {
    regex = new RegExp("\<|>");
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(val.replace(regex, ''));
});
```

This strips the `<` and `>` keys from the input on keyup. The user will see this happening, but it should always catch the desired keys and strip them.